# how To manage middleware to stay different users in there own dashboard/profile using laravel?

Tags: php, laravel

How i do that when which type of users login its stay its own dashboard/profile. User and SuperAdmin is okay,but when i login with branchAdmin account and write other users url in browser it go on its dashboard it not stay in its own account.

Routes:

```
Route::group(['middleware'  =>  [ 'auth', 'isAdmin']], function(){
        Route::get('/profile','ProfileController@getIndex');
    });

    Route::group(['middleware'  =>  [ 'auth', 'isBranchAdmin']], function(){
        Route::get('/branch','BranchController@gettIndex');
    });

    Route::group(['middleware'  =>  [ 'auth', 'isNotAdmin']], function(){
    Route::get('/Super/admin', 'AdminController@getIndex');
        });
```

View:

```
 <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-3 col-lg-3">
        @if(Auth::check() && Auth::user()->type === 'User')
            <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked">
                <li role="presentation" class="active">
                    <a id="bootstrap-overrides" href="/home">
                        Home
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li role="presentation">
                    <a id="bootstrap-overrides" href="/contact">
                        Contact
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li role="presentation">
                    <a id="bootstrap-overrides" href="/about">
                        About
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li role="presentation">
                    <a id="bootstrap-overrides" href="/blog">
                        Blog
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li role="presentation">
                    <a id="bootstrap-overrides" href="/faqs">
                        FAQs
                    </a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        @elseif(Auth::check() && Auth::user()->type === 'Admin')
            <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked">
                <li role="presentation" @if(Request::path() === 'companies') class="active" @endif>
                    <a href="/companies">
                        Companies
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li role="presentation" @if(Request::path() === 'branchies') class="active" @endif>
                    <a href="/branchies">
                        Branchies
                    </a>
                </li>
            </ul>
```

Middlewares:

UserIsAdmin:

```
class UserIsAdmin
{
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        if(Auth::user()->type === 'Admin'){
            return redirect('/Super/admin');
        }
        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

UserIsNotAdmin:

```
class UserIsNotAdmin
{
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        if(Auth::user()->type === 'User'){
            return redirect('/profile');
        }
        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

BranchAdmin:

```
class BranchAdmin 
{                note-> (" This middleware is not working ")

    public function handle($request, Closure $next){
        if(Auth::user()->type === 'BranchAdmin'){
            return redirect('/branch');
        }
        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

kernal.php:

```
protected $routeMiddleware = [
        'auth' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\Authenticate::class,
        'auth.basic' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\AuthenticateWithBasicAuth::class,
        'bindings' => \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,
        'can' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\Authorize::class,
        'guest' => \App\Http\Middleware\RedirectIfAuthenticated::class,
        'throttle' => \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\ThrottleRequests::class,
        'check_auth' => \App\Http\Middleware\CheckIfUserIsAuthenticated::class,
        'isAdmin' => \App\Http\Middleware\UserIsAdmin::class,
        'isNotAdmin' => \App\Http\Middleware\UserIsNotAdmin::class,
        'isBranchAdmin' => \App\Http\Middleware\BranchAdmin::class
    ];
```

Comment: kernel.php in App/Http can we see it ?

Comment: yes i can upload this file

Comment: in BranchAdmin middleware. are you getting too many redirects error ?

Comment: yes to many redirect error.

Comment: okay let me answer it.

Answer (score 0):

in `BranchAdmin` class in handle method where you are redirecting user to `branch` you should check that the path of the url is not `/branch` like this.

```
 public function handle($request, Closure $next){

    if(Auth::user()->type === 'BranchAdmin' && $request->path() != 'branch'){
        return redirect('/branch');
    }
    return $next($request);
 }
```

hope this helps :)